# PHP code to change image source on each page with URL or page Title

Tags: php, css, jquery-ui

I am working on running website which is loading main.php file on Each page and it has thousands of pages. Each page url is different e.g,

```
mywebsite.com/United-Kingdom.php
```

and

```
mywebsite.com/United-Stats-of-america.php.
```

each page having unique page title which is being load by PHP from Database,
(`<h4 style="font-size:20px;color:#148ADB;"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?>Information</h4>`).

i want to change header jpg image automatically with url or with page title  e.g if user go united-kingdom url than image should be loaded /images/country/united-kingdom.jpg on header and when user open United Stats page it should load image /images/country/united-stats.jpg on header.

How can i achieve this ?

= now() ORDER BY fare");

$arr1=mysql_fetch_array($sel1);

?>

```
<div id="content-top-txt" style="height:auto">
<div id="content-top-inner1">

<div id="content-top-txt-inner1" style="height:auto">       

        <div class="content">

        <h4 style="font-size:20px;color:#148ADB;"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?>specials</h4>

        <p style='text-align:justify; font-size:13px; color:#3c3c3c;'>

        <strong style="text-transform:uppercase;color:#148ADB;"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?></strong> with choice of range prices think of comfort for lesser cost<strong style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?></strong> starts from <?php

                    $tempcode=$arr1['des_code'];

                    $stemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities_var WHERE code='$tempcode'");

                    $temp=mysql_fetch_array($stemp);

                    if($temp['code']=='')

                    {                                               

                     ?>

                     <strong><?php echo $arr1['des_name'];?> (<?php echo $arr1['des_code']; ?>) </strong>

                    <?php

                    }

                    else

                    {

                    ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $temp['url'] ?>" target="_blank"><strong><?php echo $arr1['des_name'];?> (<?php echo $arr1['des_code']; ?>) </strong></a>

                    <?php

                    }

                    ?>

                    @ <strong>&pound;<?php echo $arr1['fare']; ?></strong> with & table below<?php echo $arr1['des_name'];?> & other cities in <strong style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?></strong> About<strong>UK</strong>.General information About <strong style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $cityname['country']; ?></strong>call @ 123456789 or use <a href="../../form.php">Form</a> or email:- <strong>Email@address.com</strong></p>

        <p><?php    echo $cvar['overview2']; ?></p>

        <p>Note:-Prices given are excluding taxes</p>

        </div>
```

```
<div id="content-top-inner2">

<div id="content-top-txt-inner2" style="height:auto">      

        <!-- slider start here -->

        <div class="slider-main">



        </div>   <!-- slider end here-->

        </div><!-- Content-top-txt-inner2 end-->

        </div><!-- content-top-inner2 end here-->

</div><!--contaent-top-txt end here -->

</div><!--content-top end here -->



<div id="content-middle">

<div id="content-middle-txt">   

        <?php

        include("../../files/lb1.php");

        ?>

    <div class="content-middle-txt-right">

        <?php       

        include("../../files/d-search-compare.php");            

        ?>

     </div>

     <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div class="more"><p><span>Note :&nbsp;</span><?php //echo $sql_rec['note']; ?></p><p>paragraph text.</p>
```

```
</div> <!--content-middle-txt end -->

</div>  <!--content-middle end -->
```

```
<div id="content-bottom">

<div id="content-bottom-txt">                   

    <div id="bottom-all-box">

    <?php                                       

        include("../../files/lb2.php");

    ?>

    <div id="content-bottom-right">

    <?php

        include("../../files/rb1.php");

    ?> 

    </div>

    </div>

    <?php

    /*  

        include("../../files/country-left-box3.php");

        include("../../files/country-right-box1.php");

    */

    ?>
```

Comment: PHP code to change image source on each page with URL or page Title

Comment: I tried to copy paste my code but it is not including PHP code.

Comment: Paste your code into the question, select it and press the 'code' button - it will indent it, which is the Markdown way to format code.

Comment: Dear i tried my level best to paste complete code kindly check...

Comment: Can you please take your time to place the code in a proper way. Your post is really messed up right now.

Comment: You are right mparryy and sorry for this... actually i just pasted and this website make it in parts :( anyhow i am going to try you suggestion and i hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I would change all the image names to the exact page name of the PHP file. So for example you have `/united-kingdom.php` your image should be named `united-kingdom.jpg`.

With that the same you can get the current page URL which you requested using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Now you can define the image using the current page name.

```
$url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$imageName = substr($url, 0, strpos($imageName, "."));
```

The variable `$imageName` will contain `united-kingdom`.
So you can define your image like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imageName; ?>.jpg" alt="" />
```

This code is not completely tested but is just to give you an idea on how you can handle it.